# Cannot line break in PHP using fwrite

Tags: php

I'm using this code to add user input to a text file:

```
<?php

//establish variables
$myFile = "chapter2.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$gnumber = $_POST["gnumber"];

fwrite($fh, $name); 
fwrite($fh, "\n");
fwrite($fh, $gnumber);

fclose($fh);

?>
```

However, it adds it to the text file like this:

namegnumber

Instead of this:

name

gnumber

Why does this happen?

Comment: try \r or \n\r it might make a difference

Comment: or \r\n but it's the same thing

Comment: The line ending should make no difference since the file is open in text mode (ie. not binary mode)

Comment: `\r\n` !== `\n\r`  Please use the correct order, or be subjected to random parsing problems in the future.

Comment: you render this in html? or open in notepad?

Comment: @Kolink, Surely it makes a big difference, depending on what platform and program he is using to read these files.

Comment: I am rendering this in notepad

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things you can try. The main one being: try using `fwrite($fh,PHP_EOL)` instead of `fwrite($fh,"\n");`, as this will ensure your script generates the right line ending for the OS you're on.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are viewing your output via HTML, in which case output will not be line broken with just \n.

```
fwrite($fh, "<br />".PHP_EOL);
```